# Filter ListView with arrayadapter

Tags: android, filter, android-arrayadapter

I'm trying to filter a listview with arrayadapter. The arraydapter parameter is a String[][]. The problem is that anything happens. I must override the Filter interface? In that case plase, can someone provide some hints?

Every position of the array I'm trying to filter is like

```
 galleryValues[0][0] -> "tiulo"
              [0][1] -> "desc"
              [0][2] -> "etc"
```

I tryied to filter it:

```
lstContinente = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
lstContinente.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
adapter = new PortaitArrayAdapter(cx,galleryValues);   
lstContinente.setAdapter(adapter);

ed_busqueda.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {           
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}      
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub       
}        
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();                 
}        
});
```

The adapter code:

```
public class PortaitArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private final Context context;
    private final String[][] values;
    private List<Imagen> imagenes = null;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader;     


    public PortaitArrayAdapter(Context context, String[][] values) {
        super(context, R.layout.gallery_row);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        imagenes = new ArrayList<Imagen>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) imagenes.add(new Imagen());
        Bitmap def = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.context.getResources(),R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        imageLoader=new ImageLoader(this.context,def, imagenes);
    }



    @Override
    public int getCount (){
        return this.values.length;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            convertView =  mInflater.inflate(R.layout.gallery_row, parent, false);
            holder.txtTitulo = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_gallery_titulo);
            holder.txtDesc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_gallery_desc);
            holder.txtFecha = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_gallery_fecha);
            holder.txtEst = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_gallery_est);
            holder.imageView    = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.lst_img_gallery);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }


        /*LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gallery_row, parent, false);*/

        //ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);


        Bitmap bmp;
        Log.v("Position --> ",String.valueOf(position));
        try {
            byte b[] = imagenes.get(position).getImageData();
            if (b != null) {
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(b, 0, b.length);
                if (bmp != null) holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
            } else {

                String urlBase = galleryValues[position][0].substring(0, galleryValues[position][0].lastIndexOf("/")+1);
               String urlToEncode = galleryValues[position][0].substring(galleryValues[position][0].lastIndexOf("/")+1, galleryValues[position][0].length());

               urlToEncode = URLEncoder.encode(urlToEncode,"UTF-8");

               String url = urlBase.concat(urlToEncode);

               url = url.replace("+", "%20");
               Log.v("UrlFinal --> ",url);

                imageLoader.DisplayImage(String.valueOf(position),url,act,holder.imageView, position,null);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(this.getClass().getName(),"Exception en pos = " + position + " error:" + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        holder.txtTitulo.setText(galleryValues[position][1] + ", " + galleryValues[position][2]);

        String[] dates = galleryValues[position][4].split("/");  
        String date = dates [1] + "/" + dates[0] + "/" + dates[2];
        Date d1 = new Date(date);
        DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.LONG);
        holder.txtDesc.setText(galleryValues[position][3]);

        holder.txtFecha.setText(df.format(d1));
        holder.txtEst.setText(getText(R.string.num_fotos_gallery) + galleryValues[position][5] + " - " + getText(R.string.num_videos_gallery) + galleryValues[position][6] + " - " + getText(R.string.num_exp_gallery) + galleryValues[position][7]);

        return convertView;
    }

}

private static class ViewHolder {
    TextView txtTitulo;
    TextView txtDesc;
    TextView txtFecha;
    TextView txtEst;
    ImageView imageView;
}
```

Comment: This is exactly my problem :)

Comment: Trying this `adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString(), new Filter.FilterListener() {
                  public void onFilterComplete(int count) {
                      Log.d("FILTER --> ", "filter complete! count: " + count);
                      adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                  }
              });` I noticed that the liostener is never called, you have the same error?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Convert your String array to `ArrayList` and pass it to `Adapter` and use below code or change below code with your `String[]`.

You need to implement `Filterable` to your `Adapter` class and `Override getFilter()`

Checkout [this](http://www.devdaily.com/java/jwarehouse/android/core/java/android/app/LauncherActivity.java.shtml) complete example for filtering custom `Adapter`.

```
public class ListFilterActivity extends ListActivity {

    private List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> mOriginalValues;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this, getModel());
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        EditText filterEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.filterText);

        // Add Text Change Listener to EditText
        filterEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                // Call back the Adapter with current character to Filter
                adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        });
    }

    private List<String> getModel() {
        list.add("Linux");
        list.add("Windows7");
        list.add("Suse");
        list.add("Eclipse");
        list.add("Ubuntu");
        list.add("Solaris");
        list.add("Android");
        list.add("iPhone");
        list.add("Windows XP");
        return list;
    }
}

// Adapter Class
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

    List<String> arrayList;
    List<String> mOriginalValues; // Original Values
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, List<String> arrayList) {
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView textView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if (convertView == null) {

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
            holder.textView = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.textview);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.textView.setText(arrayList.get(position));
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        Filter filter = new Filter() {

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,FilterResults results) {

                arrayList = (List<String>) results.values; // has the filtered values
                notifyDataSetChanged();  // notifies the data with new filtered values
            }

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();        // Holds the results of a filtering operation in values
                List<String> FilteredArrList = new ArrayList<String>();

                if (mOriginalValues == null) {
                    mOriginalValues = new ArrayList<String>(arrayList); // saves the original data in mOriginalValues
                }

                /********
                *
                *  If constraint(CharSequence that is received) is null returns the mOriginalValues(Original) values
                *  else does the Filtering and returns FilteredArrList(Filtered)
                *
                ********/
                if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {

                    // set the Original result to return
                    results.count = mOriginalValues.size();
                    results.values = mOriginalValues;
                } else {
                    constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
                    for (int i = 0; i < mOriginalValues.size(); i++) {
                        String data = mOriginalValues.get(i);
                        if (data.toLowerCase().startsWith(constraint.toString())) {
                            FilteredArrList.add(data);
                        }
                    }
                    // set the Filtered result to return
                    results.count = FilteredArrList.size();
                    results.values = FilteredArrList;
                }
                return results;
            }
        };
        return filter;
    }
}
```

Comment: is `publishResults()` ever called?

Answer (score 2):

**Here** I mention the code of how  We can filter the listView Data using custom Adapter
**Its really help you**

**ListViewAdapter.java**

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    // Declare Variables
    Context mContext;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    public List<AllFoodItem> allFoodItemlist;
    public ArrayList<AllFoodItem> arraylist;

    public ListViewAdapter(Context context, List<AllFoodItem> allFoodItemlist) {
        mContext = context;
        this.allFoodItemlist = allFoodItemlist;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        this.arraylist = new ArrayList<AllFoodItem>();
        this.arraylist.addAll(allFoodItemlist);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return allFoodItemlist.size();
    }

    @Override
    public AllFoodItem getItem(int position) {
        return allFoodItemlist.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public class Holder {
        TextView foodname, quantity, calorie;    
    }    
    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        Holder holder = new Holder();
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.program_list, null);
        // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
        holder.foodname = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
         // Set the results into TextViews            holder.foodname.setText(allFoodItemlist.get(position).getName().toString());    
        return view;
    }

    // Filter Class
    public void filter(String charText) {
        charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
        allFoodItemlist.clear();
        if (charText.length() == 0) {
            allFoodItemlist.addAll(arraylist);
        } else {
            for (AllFoodItem wp : arraylist) {
                if (wp.getName().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText)) {
                    allFoodItemlist.add(wp);
                }
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

**MainActivity.java**

use the ListViewAdapter class apply filter on EditText by  using filter() method

```
inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                // When user changed the Text
                foodname = (inputSearch.getText().toString()).trim();

                // filter the data of edit Text using filter method in ListViewAdapter
                String text = inputSearch.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
                adapter.filter(text);
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                          int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {

                userGet();
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
```

Comment: Please only include relevant code. I see some TODOs and empty functions that are unnecessary to include on this site

Answer (score 0):

This is Kotlin version of [venky's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10532898/1820553). Adapter part only. Studio makes many mistakes while converting. Hope it helps.

```kotlin
import android.content.Context
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import android.widget.Filter
import android.widget.Filterable
import android.widget.TextView
import com.takip.ennet.dataClasses.TaxAdministration
import java.util.Locale


class TaxAdministrationAdapter(context: Context, taxAdString: Array<String>, taxAdministrations: Array<TaxAdministration>) :
    ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, taxAdString), Filterable{

    private var arrayList = listOf<String>()
    private var mOriginalValues = taxAdString.toMutableList()

    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
        val view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent)
        val textView = view.findViewById<TextView>(android.R.id.text1)
        textView.text = getItem(position) // Set only the desired field
        return view
    }

    override fun getItem(position: Int): String? {
        return if (position >= 0 && position < count) {
            arrayList[position]
        } else {
            null
        }
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return arrayList.size
    }

    override fun getFilter(): Filter {
        return object : Filter() {
            override fun performFiltering(constraint: CharSequence?): FilterResults? {
                val results = FilterResults() // Holds the results of a filtering operation in values

                val filteredArrList = mutableListOf<String>()

                if (constraint.isNullOrEmpty()) {

                    // set the Original result to return
                    results.count = mOriginalValues.size
                    results.values = mOriginalValues
                } else {
                    var tempConstraint = constraint.toString().lowercase(Locale.ROOT)
                    for (i in mOriginalValues.indices) {
                        val data = mOriginalValues[i]
                        if (data.lowercase(Locale.getDefault()).startsWith(tempConstraint.toString())) {
                            filteredArrList.add(data)
                        }
                    }
                    // set the Filtered result to return
                    results.count = filteredArrList.size
                    results.values = filteredArrList
                }
                return results
            }

            override fun publishResults(constraint: CharSequence?, results: FilterResults?) {
                arrayList = results?.values as List<String> // has the filtered values
                notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
        }
    }

}
```