# How to make the filtered search result to display in listview in android

Tags: java, android, listview, search, android-listview

I have a edittext and a listview which contains data in it, so after giving keyword in edittext related keyword from the listview should be displayed. for this i have done the coding.. but after filter the desired item .when i click on it.it will not open that item EXAMPLE if list consist three item aa,bb and cc .if i search cc item then after click on it open aa item..so please tell me how to solve this problem...

```
           package com.example.education;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;

    public class FirstActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

private ListView listview;
private ArrayList<Temple> arraylist;
private ArrayAdapter<Temple> adapter;
            private EditText et;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    listview=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    arraylist=new ArrayList<Temple>();
    arraylist.add(new Temple("Birla","ttttt",R.drawable.birla));
    arraylist.add(new Temple("Badrinath", "ddddd",R.drawable.badrinath));
            arraylist.add(new Temple("ganga", "dddddd",R.drawable.ganga));
  adapter=new ArrayAdapter<Temple>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arraylist );
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
    listview.setOnItemClickListener(this);
   et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3)         {
            // When user changed the Text
            First.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);   
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,  int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub  

        }
});
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_first, menu);
    return true;

}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int index, long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Temple t= arraylist.get(index);
    Intent intent=new Intent(this,DetailActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("Title",t.getTitle() );
    intent.putExtra("Desc",t.getDescription() );
    intent.putExtra("Img",t.imgId );
    startActivity(intent);
}

    }
```

second class 
                    package com.example.education;

```
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class DetailActivity extends Activity {


private TextView Title;
private TextView Description;
private ImageView Image;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Image=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    Title=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    Description=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    Intent intent=getIntent();
   Title.setText(intent.getStringExtra("Title"));
   Description.setText(intent.getStringExtra("Desc"));
   Image.setImageResource(intent.getIntExtra("Img",R.drawable.ic_launcher));



}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_detail, menu);
    return true;
}

   }
```

third class
                               package com.example.education;

```
        public class Temple {
         String Title;
         String Description; 
          int imgId;
          @Override
             public String toString() {
return "" + Title;
               }
            public Temple() {
super();
// TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
             }
             public Temple(String title, String description, int imgId) {
super();
Title = title;
Description = description;
this.imgId = imgId;
              }
         public String getTitle() {
return Title;
            }
            public void setTitle(String title) {
Title = title;
             }
           public String getDescription() {
return Description;
              }
           public void setDescription(String description) {
Description = description;
              } 

            public int getImgId() {
return imgId;
             }
           public void setImgId(int imgId) {
this.imgId = imgId;
               }



              }
```

Comment: You should format your code properly to make it easier for others to read. Anyway, you may find this answer useful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10532898/826731

Answer (score 0):

Ok by reading the description, what i understand is that since there were three items e.g aa,bb and cc and searching cc in them returned one item i.e cc whose index is 0 now. When that is clicked the selected one shown is aa. The problem is with these indices. You are using the new index for cc which is 0 but showing from the old indices where o was the index of aa.

I faced exactly the same issue when I had this problem a couple of years ago. What I did was add an extra field that stored the original index as a field in an object. So when cc in the above exaple is clicked, I would do something like cc.getOriginalIndex() which would return 2 and show the result which would print fine.

If this makes sense to you, try to implement it, or we'll get into the code.