# Array Adapter - getCount return previous count

Tags: android

I'm using array adapter to implement a search view to search for hard coded elements

my code as follows

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ListView list;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.toolbar);
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    EditText edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    edittext.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row_item, COUNTRIES);
}
TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        if (s.toString().equals(""))
            list.setAdapter(null);
        else {
            adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
//                adapter.clear();
            Log.v("HEY", adapter.getCount() + "");
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }
};
private static final String[] COUNTRIES = new String[]{
        "FAAAFA", "France", "FOO"};
}
```

When i type F in the search for example, the count is printed 0 instead of 3
then when i apply any other query the count is 3 (ie it prints the count of previous query to current one)

Comment: How does the filter method look like?

Comment: i just use adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10532194/filter-listview-with-arrayadapter