# Perform/Add search functionality to a custom ListView

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-package-managers

i created a custom listView of all installed apps but i don't know how to add a search functionality because it's a little complicated(..my app) can anyone help me with that?
[(picture of the app )](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRZUP.jpg)

App.java - app constructor

```
public class App {
    private int number;
    private String name;
    private String version;
    private Drawable drawable;

    public App(int number, String name, String version, Drawable drawable){
        this.number = number;
        this.name = name;
        this.version = version;
        this.drawable = drawable;
    }
    //Getters & Setters...
}
```

AppAdapter.java - listView Adapter

```
public class AppAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<App> {
    Context context;
    List<App> objects;

    public AppAdapter(Context context, int resources, int textViewResources, List<App> objects){
        super(context, resources, textViewResources, objects);

        this.context = context;
        this.objects = objects;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_card,parent,false);

        TextView tvName =  (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        TextView tvVersion =  (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tvVersion);
        TextView tvNumber =  (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tvNumber);
        ImageView ivImage = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.ivImage);

        App current = objects.get(position);
        tvName.setText(String.valueOf(current.getName()));
        tvVersion.setText(String.valueOf(current.getVersion()));
        tvNumber.setText(String.valueOf(current.getNumber()));
        ivImage.setImageDrawable(current.getDrawable());

        return view;
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {   
    ArrayList<App> appList;
    ListView lv;
    AppAdapter appAdapter;
    App lastSelected;
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        EditText etSearch = findViewById(R.id.etSearch);
        
        PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
        List<PackageInfo> mApps = packageManager.getInstalledPackages(0);
        //array strings to all packages, names and version
        final String[] arrPackages = new String[mApps.size()];
        final String[] arrVersion = new String[mApps.size()];
        String[] arrName = new String[mApps.size()];
        //array of Drawables for icons...
        Drawable[] arrIcons = new Drawable[mApps.size()];
        App[] arrApps = new App[mApps.size()];
        appList = new ArrayList<>();
        //reading all app's packages and version to the arrays
        for (int i = 0; i < mApps.size(); i++){
            arrVersion[i] = mApps.get(i).versionName;
            arrPackages[i] = mApps.get(i).packageName;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < mApps.size(); i++){
            try {//getting app's names from theres packages
                arrName[i] = (String) packageManager.getApplicationLabel(packageManager.getApplicationInfo(arrPackages[i], PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));
            } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                arrName[i] = "Unknown";
            }

            try {//same as names for icons
                arrIcons[i] = packageManager.getApplicationIcon(arrPackages[i]);
            } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                arrIcons[i] = getDrawable(R.drawable.placeholder);
            }
            arrApps[i] = new App(i + 1, "Name: "+arrName[i], "Version: "+arrVersion[i], arrIcons[i]);
            appList.add(arrApps[i]);
        }
        //on item click open app
        appAdapter = new AppAdapter(this,0,0,appList);
        lv = findViewById(R.id.lv);
        lv.setAdapter(appAdapter);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                lastSelected = appAdapter.getItem(position);
                Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(arrPackages[position]);
                if (launchIntent != null) {
                    startActivity(launchIntent);//null pointer check in case package name was not found
                }
            }
        });

        //(trying to..) Add Text Change Listener to EditText
        etSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                // Call back the Adapter with current character to Filter
                MainActivity.this.appAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
            }
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,int after) {
            }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        });
    }
}
```

(when i try to search something it's gives nothing...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

exchange this line

```
App current = objects.get(position);
```

to this

```
App current = (App) getItem(position);
```

you don't need to keep `List<App> objects;` inside your adapter, it is passed in constructors `super` call (last param) and kept under the hood for you. check out [ArrayAdapter source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java) - passed `ArrayList` is kept as `mObjects` and further used in some methods, e.g. `getPosition`, `getCount` and `getItem`

`ArrayAdapter` already `implements Filterable`, so there is an overriden method `getFilter`, which returns `ArrayFilter` - this inner class is declared on the bottom. when you call `getFilter().filter(` then `performFiltering` gets called (in a separated thread) and iterates through local copy of your data (line 588). It is using `values.get(i).toString().toLowerCase()` to compare objects from array with passed `String` (`CharSequence` in fact). so in your custom `App` class override `toString` method and return in there some searchable value, e.g.

```
@Override
public String toString(){
    return name;
}
```

this is not best approach, because `toString` may be used in a lot of mechanisms (its base method of [Object](http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/lang/Object-source.html)) and with above `toString` implementation two `App`s with same name, but different `version` or `number` are threated as same object, which isn't true... maybe better way would be to `return name+version+number;`, but still you have also `Drawable` in there. thats why I've suggested (in this answer before edit) to make own class extends `BaseAdapter` and implement own filtering or at least use `ArrayAdapter`, but override `getFilter` method and return your own `Filter` implementation comparing variables instead of using `toString`. Then won't be needed to override this class, leave it as it is. By default it returns kind-of memory address, so it is unique for every new `App` instance, even when created with exacly same variables

also in [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10532194/filter-listview-with-arrayadapter) answer you can find nice example how to implement that `Filter`

Comment: tanks a lot, problem solved!!
can you explain to me what i just did? how it solved?(only if it's no trouble...)

Comment: consider upvoting/accepting my answer if helped :) I will add some more explanation tomorrow